# How to create an ORC file in Hive CDH?

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, dataformat, hortonworks-data-platform

I can easily create an ORC file format in Apache Hadoop or Hortonworks' HDP:

```
CREATE TABLE ... STORED AS ORC
```

However this doesn't work in Cloudera's CDH 4.5. (Surprise!) I get:

> FAILED: SemanticException Unrecognized file format in STORED AS clause: ORC

So as an alternative, I tried to download and install the Hive jar that contains the ORC classes:

```
hive> add jar /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.5.0-1.cdh4.5.0.p0.30/lib/hive/lib/hive-exec-0.11.0.jar;
```

Then create my ORC Table:

```
hive>    CREATE TABLE test (name STRING)

> row format serde
> 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde'
>  stored as inputformat
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat'   
>   outputformat
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat';
OK
```

But upon inserting into this table from some CSV data, I get an error:

```
hive> INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE test 
> SELECT name FROM textdata;

    Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:413)
```

How should I create an ORC table in Hive in CDH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CDH 4.5 contains Hive 0.10, see [CDH Version 4.5.0 Packaging and Tarballs](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/latest/CDH-Version-and-Packaging-Information/cdhvd_topic_3.html). ORC was added in Hive 0.11, see [release notes](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?version=12323587&styleName=Text&projectId=12310843) and [HIVE-3874: Create a new Optimized Row Columnar file format for Hive](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-3874).

CDH 5 is in Beta now but it does contain Hive 0.11, see [CDH Version 5.0.0 Beta 1](https://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH5/latest/CDH-Version-and-Packaging-Information/cdhvd_topic_3.html).